# Oracle - Identificar linea en la cual sucede excepcion

Tags: oracle

alguien me puede decir como identifico la línea de código en la cual sucede una excepción en oracle, lo que quiero hacer es cuando salte una excepción, agarrar la descripción y la linea y guardarlo en una tabla de errores, así podré identificar en que parte del paquete no se tiene controlado las excepciones.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo [la documentación de oracle](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2) sería tan sencillo cómo invocar:

```
LOG ERRORS [INTO [schema.]table] [('simple_expression')] [REJECT LIMIT integer|UNLIMITED]
```

Comment: Pero yo quisiera agarrar en la excepcion de un SP, o sea dentro la excepcion agarrar esos detalles de la exscepcion y registrarlos en otra tabla.